# webpack build an original in tree

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webstorm

After webpack build & push bundle.js to the server, in a tree of sources has a branch to original code from webpack:// ...
[image: source tree]

Answer (score 0):

in webpack.config.js need key
module.exports = {
...
devtool: `false`,
...
}